# List all the users who currently logged in to the unix server

Tags: bash, shell, unix

In unix, I use the `who`-command to list out all the users who currently logged in to the system.
I wish to write a `bash` shell script which displays the same outputs as the `who`-command.
I have tried the following:

1. `vi log.sh` -now there is a file `log.sh`
2. now, typed `who`
3. save and quit
4. give execute permission: `chmod +x log.sh`
5. execute: `sh -vx log.sh`

This will give the same output as using `who`.
However, is there another way to write such a shell script?

Comment: While technically correct, I highly doubt a wrapper around `who` is what your teacher had in mind.

Comment: What flavor of Unix are you using? On Mac OS X, `who` reads from`/var/tmp/utmpx`; in Linux, it reads from `/var/tmp/utmp`. Man pages (`man utmpx`, `man utmp`) document the format of each.

Comment: You can start with `utmpdump /var/run/utmp`. I just don't know how you can parse that.

Comment: @konsolebox _At first sight_ this might correspond to the C-structure given in `man utmp`.

Comment: @SylvainLeroux I've seen that. However I didn't think that it would really be helpful when it comes to parsing with a shell script.

Comment: I don't really care actually. The homework was given without a proper rationale. Why would someone try to give same output from that of `who` out of a shell script when the sources in question are binary files.

Comment: @Cyrus what exactly you want to say with your answer ? Please read the question before answering

Comment: @Maverick If this is _not_ homework, you definitively have to explain why you can't use `who` and why you have to rewrite it "using bash". Even on very constrained system, this might be build as part of [Busybox](http://www.busybox.net/downloads/BusyBox.html) without much space penalty.

Comment: I faced this type of questions multiple times in Interview .. i answered whatever i have mentioned in my post ...i'm not asking for forcefully to answer my question , i'm asking for suggestions " is there another ways or not " because interviewer was not happy with my answers

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it appears to be asking for the answer to a homework question. The effort shown is minimal.

Comment: `echo -e '#!/bin/bash\nwho' > log.sh; chmod u+x log.sh; ./log.sh`

Comment: @konsolebox Given the various comments of the OP, we might afford some creativity here. So taking one of your comments as a challenge I've posted an other answer to this question. After all, basic parsing of `utmp` wasn't _that_ difficult. Obviously not for production code though!

Comment: @SylvainLeroux I could also hack through it if I really want to. But this time I really don't find it sensible and worth it.

Comment: @Maverick _"I faced this type of questions multiple times in Interview [..] interviewer was not happy with my answers"_ Maybe he/she was expecting some creative answer and/or was testing your ability to think critically about "requirements". As a matter of fact, the various comments here provides _many_ hints and clues about _how_ to answer to such a question.

Comment: @konsolebox It was mostly "for fun" I must admit ;)

Comment: @SylvainLeroux Don't get my statement earlier wrong that it was an assumption that it is impossible in shell scripting - granting you have the aid of other tools. It's just not worth it. Better do it in C instead.

Answer (score 3):

It is hard to answer as I suspect this is homework (and *I don't want* give you the full answer). Moreover I don't know how proficient you might be in various programming area. So, I will only try to make an answer that is in accordance with the [How do I ask and answer Homework Community Wiki](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10812/229922)

> Is there another way?....

Yes it is. Obviously: `who` has to work somehow. At the very worst, you might search into the source code to know *how* it works.

---

Fortunately this question does not require such extreme solution. As it has been said in a comment, `who` reads from `/var/tmp/utmp` or `/var/run/utmp` on my Debian system.

```
cat /var/run/utmp
```

You will see this is a binary "file". You have to somehow decode it. That's where `man utmp` might came to an help. It will expose the C structure corresponding to one record in the `utmp` file.

With that knowledge, you will be able to process the file with your favorite language. Please note `bash` (or any shell) is probably *not* the best language to deal with binary data structures.

---

As I said first, you didn't give enough background for I (us?) to give some precise advices. Anyway, if digging into  the kernel data-structures is ... well ... way above what can be expected from you, maybe some "simple" solution based on `grep`/`awk`/`bash`/*`whatever`* might be sufficient to filter the output of:

```
ps -edf
```

Comment: This is not my homework , i have been working in application/production support for four months , So i need help with it , By the way Thank you for reply

Answer (score 0):

Taking this as a challenge, I come with this solution:

```
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s extglob
while read record; do
    # ut_name at offset 44 size 32
    ut_name="${record:44:32}"
    # ut_line at offset 8 size 32
    ut_line="${record:8:32}"
    echo ${ut_name%%*(.)} ${ut_line%%*(.)}
done < <(hexdump -v -e '384/1 "%_p"' -e '"\n"' /var/run/utmp)
#                       ^^^
#          according to utmp.h, sizeof(struct utmp) is 384 bytes
#          so hexdump outputs here one line for each record.
```

As `bash` is not good at handling binary data (especially containing `\x00`) I had to rely on `hexdump` with a custom format to "decode" `utmp` records.

Of course, this is far from being perfect, and producing and output really identical to the one given by `who` might require some decent amount of efforts. But this might be a good starting point...

Comment: You can consider using `IFS= read -rd '' record` and read null-terminated strings over reading newlines.

Comment: @konsolebox Maybe? I'm not sure to understand you point here. As this is a binary format, there might be `\x00` at various places in the record. But one thing I knew (from `utmp.h`) was each record has 384 bytes. That's why I instructed `hexdump` to produces lines of 384 chars. In other words, each line is a `struct utmp` record (with non-printing chars replaced).

Comment: I see. I now know what you mean.